# Make words of a string selectable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I need to make words in a string select-able using regular expression in Javascript by adding span tag around select-able word. There are few conditions for a word to be select-able. They are,

1) A selectable word can consist of alphabets and numeric value, separated by space.

2) Any special character or combination of special characters appearing in-between word will also be part of selectable text. E.g. HTML#CSS is a single selectable word

3) Any special character or combination of special characters appearing in front or behind word won’t be selectable. E.g. HTML #CSS are two selectable words (HTML and CSS)

Exception to point 3
- $ (dollar sign) in front of word will be part of select-able word.
- ' (apostrophe sign) at end of word will be part of select-able word.

For example,

```
$45 will be <span>$45</span>
#45 will be #<span>45</span>
end. will be <span>end</span>.
said' will be <span>said'</span>
html#css will be <span>html#css</span>
```

Can anybody help me with regular expression for this? I am available if more information/clarification is needed. Thank you.

This is what I have come up till now - `/([A-Za-z0-9\$]+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)([A-Za-z0-9']+)/g`
but it runs successfully if there is atleast 3 chars in a word.

Comment: post the regular expression you've tried.

Comment: /([A-Za-z0-9\$]+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)([A-Za-z0-9']+)/g

Comment: Why this has being down-voted??

Comment: You hadn't shown any code / effort in how you'd solve it, now I see your regex, I got rid of the downvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?:\s|^)([^a-zA-Z\d\$]*?)([a-zA-Z\d\$][^\s]*?)([^a-zA-Z0-9'-]*?)(?=\s|$)
```

and now you can replace it like this

```
$1<span>$2</span>$3
```

Comment: hmm.. not working. String, On personal a computers. 24  12. got converted to <span>On</span>personal a computers.<span>24</span> 12.

Comment: @RohitSinghSengar ahh..finally works..i got clear idea with ur example..would work now..check out the ans

Comment: hmm.. impressive. Almost. Although single letter/character is still left out. That I guess can figure out.

Comment: @RohitSinghSengar are u talking about space

Comment: It is converting String: On personal a computers. 24  12. running?</example> TO: <span>On</span>$3 <span>personal</span>$3 a <span>computers</span>$3 <span>24</span>$3 <span>12</span>$3 <span>running</span>$3    dot & ? are lost & $3 coming as it is.

Comment: @RohitSinghSengar worked [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=4f78bcc7-0214-4c73-bd7f-87ea121e63f2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18873/discussion-between-rohit-singh-sengar-and-fake-it-til-u-make-it)